# Get value from a repeatable field and use it in a module

Tags: module, repeatable-field

I use the field type "repeatable" in a Joomla module I've created but I don't know how to get the values out of it and use it in the module's default.php to create the output.

My repeatable field:

```
                    <field name="mitarbeiter"
                    type="Repeatable"
                    icon="list"
                    description="Mitarbeiter eingeben"
                    label="Mitarbeiter eingeben"
                    <fields name="params">
                        <fieldset hidden="true" name="mitarbeiter_template_modal" repeat="true">

                        <field name="mitarbeitername"
                            label="Name"
                            size="30"
                            type="text" />

                        <field name="mitarbeiterfunktion"
                            label="Funktion"
                            size="30"
                            type="text" />

                        <field name="mitarbeitertelefonnummer"
                            label="Funktion"
                            size="30"
                            type="text" />

                        <field name="mitarbeiteremail"
                            label="Funktion"
                            size="30"
                            type="text" />

                        <field name="mitarbeiterbild"
                            label="Bild-URL"
                            size="30"
                            type="text" />

                        </fieldset>
                    </fields>
                </field>
```

Normally I get the value of a field in the mod_modulename.php:

```
$fieldvalue = $parameters->get('fieldname');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Value of Repeatable Field from Joomla XML manifest](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/get-value-of-repeatable-field-from-joomla-xml-manifest)

Comment: Hi Farahmand. The answer in this post is bad and in my opition the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping someone would eventually ask this question on here. I wrote a function for my first usage of repeatable form fields and use it for every extension I make now.

Here is how you do it:

Firstly, get the json object for the parameter like so:

```
$mitarbeiter = $params->get('mitarbeiter');
```

Then decode the json object:

```
$json = json_decode($mitarbeiter, true);
```

Then can then group each set of fields by key, like so:

```
public function group_by_key($array) 
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $sub) 
    {
        foreach ($sub as $k => $v) 
        {
            $result[$k][] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$filtered_array = group_by_key($json);
```

And finally, you'll need to iterate though it using a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach ($filtered_array as $index=>$value) 
{   
    echo $value[0] . '<br>';   // mitarbeitername
    echo $value[1] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiterfunktion
    echo $value[2] . '<br>';   // mitarbeitertelefonnummer
    echo $value[3] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiteremail
    echo $value[4] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiterbild
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! Youre solution looks pretty good. Unfortunately im not a php programmer so ive got a problem. I put the code in my mod_module.php and the foeach loop in the tmlp/default.php. Now the page is not working anymore, its showing a problem on line 29 which is the line the public function starts. Any idea what im doing wrong? Thx for your help.

Comment: Could you specify the "problem" please? If any errors are being shown, please let me know

Comment: Error message: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

I put the code inside my mod_modulname.php

Comment: Try changing `public function` to just `function`

Comment: @Peesen87 - You're more than welcome. Could you please accept the answer to mark it as solved by clicking the "tick" icon.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer from @Lodder is correct, but you will also need to wrap the function with

```
if (!function_exists('yourFunctionname')) {
    // ... proceed to declare your function
}
```

If you do not, you can only render this function once per page.

So altogether it should look like this:

```
$mitarbeiter = $params->get('mitarbeiter');
$json = json_decode($mitarbeiter, true);

if (!function_exists('group_by_key')) {
  public function group_by_key($array) 
  {
      $result = array();

      foreach ($array as $sub) 
      {
          foreach ($sub as $k => $v) 
          {
              $result[$k][] = $v;
          }
      }
      return $result;
  }
}
$filtered_array = group_by_key($json);

foreach ($filtered_array as $index=>$value) 
{   
    echo $value[0] . '<br>';   // mitarbeitername
    echo $value[1] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiterfunktion
    echo $value[2] . '<br>';   // mitarbeitertelefonnummer
    echo $value[3] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiteremail
    echo $value[4] . '<br>';   // mitarbeiterbild
}
```

Comment: Isn't it that part = if (!function_exists('yourFunctionname')) {
  public function group_by_key($array)  should be = if (!function_exists('group_by_key')) {
  public function group_by_key($array)

Comment: Yes, good catch , I will edit