# Display values of JFormFieldRepeatable

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am using a J3.x Plugin called Aixeena CCK http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/aixeena-cck which adds extra fields to articles using standard JForm field types.

I have set up a repeatable form field type https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type which simply has text boxes as follows:

```
<field name="addresses" type="Repeatable" icon="list" description="" label="Addresses" default="">
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset hidden="true" name="addresses_modal" repeat="true">
            <field name="address" label="Address" size="60" type="text" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</field>
```

In my article override I have the following code:

```
<?php
$attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);
print_r($attribs->addresses);
?>
```

This returns:

{"address":["My Address 1","My Address 2"]}

"Great!" I thought, I'll just use a foreach loop to get the individual values. So I used the following code:

```
<?php
foreach($attribs->addresses as $address){
    echo $address;
}
?>
```

However, that didn't work. I just got an error saying: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

So my question is; how do I get each individual value stored in this string?

EDITED

Results of `var_dump($attribs->addresses);`

```
string(135) "{"address":["My Address 1","My Address 2"]}"
```

EDITED AGAIN

Thanks to @Lodder I am now using:

```
$attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);
$addresses = $attribs->addresses;
$addresses = json_decode($addresses, true);
foreach ($addresses as $index=>$address) 
    {   
        echo $address[0] . '<br>';
        echo $address[1];
    }
```

This returns:
    My Address 1
    My Address 2

This is great but my question now is; how do I automatically perform the foreach loop? What I mean is; at the moment I have to add `echo $address[1]` then `echo $address[2]` etc. But the point of a repeatable field is that the user can add as many fields as they want. I hope I am making sense :)

SOLVED:

```
$attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);
$addresses = $attribs->addresses;
$addresses = json_decode($addresses);
foreach ($addresses as $index=>$addresses) 
    {   
        foreach($addresses as $address){
            echo '<p>'.$address.'</p>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you use `var_dump($attribs->addresses);` and add the results to your question?

Comment: Hi @Lodder, I have updated my question, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe try using `true` as an argument in the `json_decode` to make it an array, then do `foreach($attribs['addresses'] as ...`. Did you have a look at my answer I wrote a while back? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/module-get-value-from-repeatable-field

Comment: Hi @Lodder, I think I am getting somewhere, please have a look at my edit :)

Comment: You solved it then? :) Don't forget to write your solution as an answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big thank you to @Lodder (as always) for helping me with this. I don't know if my answer is the best way of acheiving the desired result but it works and that's what matters.

Here's what I used:

```
$attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);
$addresses = $attribs->addresses;
$addresses = json_decode($addresses);
foreach ($addresses as $index=>$addresses) 
    {   
        foreach($addresses as $address){
            echo $address;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.